# SQL show two columns of data from different tables side by side without join

Tags: mysql

I have two tables which both have column called identity_type, which takes on one of 10 values.

Identity_type has the same values in both tables.

I want to be able to show the count of each identity_type for each table side by side, without trying to join the data. Is this possible?

I.e., what I'm trying to show is the output of:

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY identity_type
```

for table_1 and table_2 side by side.

Comment: Get us some sample data and expected result is more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't join the tables side by side without using some kind of join (and even if you could, why would you want to avoid using join syntax?).

Also, this is unlikely to be valid:

SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY identity_type

All fields need to either be included in the "group by" or part of an aggregate function.

You could show them one below the other by using a UNION ALL.  You would still be querying both tables.  However, you would not be using a JOIN.

Comment: I guess my question is -- would a join try to match up rows from one table with the rows on the other? Thus if I were going to do count(*) for each identity_type for each column, it would only get the count of those rows that could be matched between the two columns? What I want is the entire count for each identity_type for each column.

Comment: An inner join on identity_type would give you matches only on the identity_types that are in both tables.     A left join or a right join would give you all the values from 1 table matched to whatever records exist for those identity types in the other table.  A full outer join will give you all the identity types from both tables. If I understand correctly you want something like this: select a.identity_type, count(a.identity_type),b.identity_type, count(b.identity_type)
from table1 a
full outer join table2 b on b.identity_type=a.identity_type
group by a.identity_type, b.identity_type

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No

Long one: First, you need to add group attribute in `SELECT` statement when you use aggregate functions to `GROUP BY`. Meaning, `SELECT identity_type, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY identity_type`. Even when you joined the tables, since there will be two different grouping, database engine cannot show two grouping at the same time. If you really need to see that kind of output, you probably can do that with some advanced `JOIN` and `PIVOT` syntax but I do not think you would want to do that.